# Capistrano check permission always not writable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, capistrano

I use capistrano to check permisson of my `deploy_to` path, it's alway output `path is not writable on mydomain.com` even though i give it 777 rights.

```
ls -ld /srv/www/
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jul 20 15:24 /srv/www/
```

Here is the task:

```
desc "Check that we can access everything"
  task :check_write_permissions do
    on roles(:all) do |host|
      if test("[ -w #{fetch(:deploy_to)} ]")
        info "#{fetch(:deploy_to)} is writable on #{host}"
      else
        error "#{fetch(:deploy_to)} is not writable on #{host}"
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Is it literally `path` in `path is not writable? If so you've got `deploy_to` set wrong.

Comment: Yeah @PhilipHallstrom My bad! deploy_to i both in `staging.rb` and `deploy.rb`

Answer (score 0):

I set `deploy_to` in both `staging.rb` and `deploy.rb`, the former override the latter.